# How do I declare a variable with a different value depending on an if statement?

Tags: java, inheritance

I am a java beginner and I am using class inheritance. I have defined an abstract class  Taula2D and two subclasses  Taula2DVersio1 and  Taula2DVersio2.
The short version of my problem: I can define a variable Tau like this without any problem.

```
Taula2DVersio1 Tau = new Taula2DVersio1(al,am);
```

If I define a variable Tau like this (class depending on condition)

```
 if (!(Versio==1)) {
        Taula2DVersio2 Tau = new Taula2DVersio2(al,am); // alçada,amplada
    }
    else  {
                Taula2DVersio1 Tau = new Taula2DVersio1(al,am);
    }
```

Then the next reference to variable Tau causes a compilation error: “cannot find symbol”

Which is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Post the full error. If you're defining a variable within an `if` (block) though, you can't use it outside of the `if`. You'll need to review variable scoping.

Comment: Separately: `if (!(Versio==1)) {` => `if (Versio != 1) {` or even better, `if (Versio == 1) {` and swap the contents of the `if` and `else` blocks.

Comment: The problem is that the variable only exists in the block (`{}`) that it is declared in. Move the declaration out.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably refering to this variable outside of `if else` block. If you define it like this it's only available in this block and if you want to use it before or after this block it won't be available.

You should define this variable outside of `if else` block like this and it will be available everywhere:

```
 Taula2D Tau;

 if (!(Versio==1)) {
    Tau = new Taula2DVersio2(al,am); // alçada,amplada
 } else  {
    Tau = new Taula2DVersio1(al,am);
 }
```

Like T.J. Crowder mentioned in the comment, alternatively you can use conditional operator which in this case is exact equivalent of `if else`:

`Taula2D Tau = Versio == 1 ? new Taula2DVersio1(al,am) : new Taula2DVersio2(al,am);`

PS: [Coding conventions in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) assume starting variable name with small letter.

Comment: Alternately: `Taula2D Tau = Versio == 1 ? new Taula2DVersio1(al,am) : new Taula2DVersio2(al,am);`